# Why do accelerometers have holes etched in their masses?

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, mems

I have been studying MEMS for a while now and I noticed that in almost every accelerometer design there are holes etched in the mass that is attached to the hinge. Why is that?

A thing I thought of is that the masses are so tight to the packaging that pressure on one side could affect the mass if it was moved or shaken with. But that would be easily solvable by putting it in a low vacuum.

I attached a schematic drawing of an accelerometer that we used.

[image: Schematic drawing of an accelerometer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The holes are apparently to control the damping. Damping appears to be passive on most of the accelerometer designs so the flow of the gas through the holes will determine the damping. Damping is important- you don't want the proof mass to bounce around too much. Ideally it should be more-or-less critically damped, I think.

Without the holes, the mechanism of film fluid flow would be different- and possibly less linear, leading to bad effects such as excessive vibration rectification.

Answer (score 0):

The frame size reinforces the acceleration mode of the "proof mass frame" along the axis of the end-mounted piezo-resistor.

Since proof mass affects frequency response it is hollow to extend the spring-mass bandwidth with dampening controlled by the inner frame material.

3  Structural members ensure resonance in the other axis is well above the sensor axis  bandwidth.